# ui.router not showing the page [nested view]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing, nested-views

I know this is a well asked question but may be my "googleing" skills are not good enough to get me what I want.

So I have a page with `ng-view` that is the main **index.html**

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 70px;" ui-view></div>
```

Now I have a view with a template url of **student.html**

```
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1" ng-controller="Controller_Parent">
<div ng-cloak>
    <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom>
        <md-tab label="View Profile" ui-view="student.profile">
        </md-tab>
        <md-tab label="View Results" ui-view="student.result">
        </md-tab>
        <md-tab label="View Attendance" ui-view="student.attendance">
        </md-tab>
    </md-tabs>
</div>
</div>
```

As the code suggests that in the `Controller_A` I want three views (sub-views to be correct) each having its own template.

The routing code is this:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {    
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
    }).state('student',{
        url:'/student',
        views:{
            '@':{
                templateUrl: 'templates/student.html',
            },
            'profile@student':{
                templateUrl:'templates/student/profile.html'
            },
        }
    });
});
```

What chages should I make to make this idea work. I have gone through the tutorials and unfortunately none of them have similar working or may be I'm looking in the wrong space.

Awaiting your input. Regards!

PS: no JS errors are thrown

Comment: Are you changing your state to `student`? Beside avoid using ng-controller inside your html.

Comment: Yes. This is a dashboard page (student.html) so it is redirect to student via login page

Comment: @krutkowski86 btw i added abstract to student class on which angular gives the error `Error: Cannot transition to abstract state 'student'`

Comment: Might be worth throwing this into a plunkr or jsfiddle so we can have an easier play about

Comment: I'll do that asap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names. It seems that you are mixing view names like `student.profile` with the referencing syntax (`viewname@statename`). So try omitting the `student.` in your template.

Also you should register your controller in the state config (probably with a common parent state) instead of the template directly...

Comment: Just tried it. Still doesn't work. Do I need to call $state.transition or some sort?

Answer (score 1):

I've made jsfiddle which is similar to your code and it does work.
The main difference is that you shouldn't prefix nested views inside ui-view directive with `student.`

http://jsfiddle.net/irhabi/3ozfxmfx/

```
<md-tab label="View Profile" ui-view="profile"></md-tab>
<md-tab label="View Results" ui-view="result"></md-tab>
<md-tab label="View Attendance" ui-view="attendance"></md-tab>
```

Comment: Nope. @ajaegle said the same and still doesn't work. No view or error.

Comment: Add this to your app if you want to see ui-router errors.
.run(function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', console.log.bind(console));
  })

Comment: Just for checking purpose i moved the `ui-view` from `md-tab` to a div inside `md-tab`, and it works. I guess the problem was with `md-tabs` not being able to work with `ui-view`